# Is there if-else block in bitbucket pipleline?

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I am using bitbucket pipeline to deploy my code.I have multiple environment.but I want to do different jobs depending on the environment(dev test pre-prod prod).I want to if there is if-else conditional ways to help me reduce duplicate code and make code less enough

Answer (score 2):

If your pipeline includes only default, it will execute in all envs.

You can include keywords in your pipeline to deal with that. In execution order, will be something like:

```
image: node:9.8.0
pipelines:
  branches: 
        #here, i'm saying to execute the step below only on branchs
    develop:
        #Here, when branch 'develop' 
     - step:
          script:
    master:
        #Here, when branch 'master' 
     - step:
          name: Buid Prod
          script:
          [....]
```

You can define other keywords to tell bitbucket when execute the steps, [see more here, at docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-bitbucket-pipelines-yml-792298910.html#Configurebitbucket-pipelines.yml-keywordsKeywords)

Comment: it is not what I want.if-else block can use through

Comment: - if [[ ]];then

Comment: Are u trying to gain some points in stackoverflow, responding your own question? Because, your question is about do different jobs depending on env. My answer should be correct.

Answer (score 1):

it can be done by the below sample

```
- if []; then
-   #task
- elif []; then
-   #task
- else
-   #task
- fi
```

Answer (score 1):

The first solution for the custom (manual) pipeline: you have to add variables to your drop-down [like](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/variables-in-pipelines-794502608.html) Then you can add if statement to check these variables like that:

```
pipelines:
   custom:
    Deploy:
      - variables:
        - name: Environment
        - name: Other-Enviromnts
      - step:
         name: NEW-Service
         script: 
          - some
          - bash 
          - comands
          - echo "$Environment"
          - 'if [ -z Environment ]
                  then 
                     echo " Environment variables is empty"
                 else 
                   echo "deploy to $Environment"
                 fi'
```

The second solution for the automated build for the pipeline with any changing in the repository:- you should set this variable `BITBUCKET_DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT` at the global environment for the pipeline in your repository setting  the same [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/variables-in-pipelines-794502608.html) I had mentioned in the first solution and the same pipeline but replace `custom` with `default`

Comment: It looks more like comment then an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead); instead, provide answers according to [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Anna more details added ;)